# How can I adjust and fix the size of the icons on the Ubuntu 18.04's desktop?

Tags: icons, 18.04, gnome-shell

How can I adjust and fix the size of the icons on the Ubuntu 18.04's desktop?

https://youtu.be/Zqgdb9WBotU

I want the size of the icons on the 18.04's desktop not changed when changing the size of the file managers' icons.

As you can see, the size of the icons on the 16.04's desktop never be changed.

Comment: The video was kind of confusing and distracting.  I couldn't make out what you're trying to do by watching the video.  I didn't watch the whole video.  It might be easier if you used screenshots of what you consider as the problem, and possibly use arrows and circles to focus on the points.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I'm not native english. I  want the size of the icons on the 18.04's desktop not changed when changing the size of the file managers' icons. As you can see,  the size of the icons on the 16.04's desktop never be changed.

Comment: I understand your issue now.  Your video and description are clear.  Will update with what I find.